# I have changed the scope of my maven dependencies to provided

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, maven

I have changed the scope of my maven dependencies to provided and manually copied to tomcat/lib (to reduce my war file size).

My app now fails to deploy with a dreaded out of memory error.

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-3
```

It is a java/spring/hibernate app. Two itneresting errors on stacktrace

```
Dec 27, 2012 2:22:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

followed by

```
Dec 27, 2012 2:22:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.jsp.myLogin_jsp] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.jsp.myLogin_jsp
```

This is outside of my IDE, when I run using intellij it works fine ... ?

**setting CATALINA_OPTS in my start up script fixes the problem, why ?**

Comment: what are the JVM settings?

Comment: @Woot4Moo unchanged from when dependies were not provided but included in war file.

Comment: A stacktrace would be nice...

Comment: Looks like it is not finding org.apache.jsp.jsp.myLogin_jsp, is that class on the classpath?

Comment: Good, now can you get a [javadump](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/tools/javadump_trigger.html) in both cases, and post what's printed for the `PSPermGen` line (right at the end).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add for example -XX:MaxPermSize=128M JVM parameter, and see what's happening.

There is one interesting of this what you did. It is descrebed [here](http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/). Shortly, the war would be smaller, but runtime memory consumption would be higher.

Comment: Class loaders in tomcat (and all java servlet containers) are organized like tree. You have one "Common" class loader which loads common classes (where are jar which exists in lib folder of tomcat). That class loader is parent class loader, and under it are class loaders for every application deployed. I think the problem here is that you overloaded common class loader little bit with these jars, so it needs more perm space.

Comment: so I moved the heavy lifting from my war file to the java class loader, thanks. 128m seems to work fine.

Comment: But there's only one PermGen, no matter which classloader is used for each class. So, moving jars from one place to another should have a marginal effect on used memory. So I was wondering if before the move the PermGen space was actually very close to being full, or if there's a huge leap in consumed memory.

Comment: Yes, that's truth. But, there is one interesting of this what NimChimpsky did. It is descrebed [here](http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/). Shortly, the war would be smaller, but runtime memory consumption would be higher.

Comment: Great link, you should add it to the answer )

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu so I shouldn't do it ?  my war goes from 20mb to 0.5mb. Makes deployment much faster. But do not want any nasty side effects ...

Comment: He, that's the engineer job. Balancing between two nasty things, and don't give any of them to rule. If your application is only one deployed, and you can restart tomcat when you redeploy it I think it is OK to leave it as you done.